# iOS push token still valid after erasing an iPhone

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So, I have an app in the store, I have downloaded it on my phone and obtained push token for that device. I tested silent push notification sending and indeed, it works, my device received it.

I wanted to check what is the time after push token will become invalid. First thing I did was simply uninstalled an app and was paying attention after which time I will start getting `{"reason":"Unregistered","timestamp:1234567890}` to my `curl` request which looks like this:

```
curl -d '{"aps":{"content-available":"1"}}' --cert "/Users/uerceg/Desktop/ProductionCertForMyAppsPush.pem":"password" -H "apns-topic:com.my.app" --http2 https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Once I have uninstalled an app from my device, it generally varies from case to case (I guess Feedback Service has some kind of tokens refresh logic I am not really aware of, nor I found some documentation about it, anyway), but it takes from 3-12 minutes to start receiving information that my app is uninstalled. Lovely.

After that, I wanted to test one more case - selecting `Erase All Content and Settings` and completely wiping out everything from my iPhone without restoring any backup afterwards.

Once I did that, app is removed as well. But `curl` request is always returning status `200`. I waited for 5 days and after 5 days, it is still returning `200` as if app is installed, but my guess is that it shouldn't. Once erasing everything, I have newly installed my app, got new push token which I use to successfully send silent push notifications again.

Sure, if I have mechanism to identify that this particular device newly installed an app, I can update the token on the backend side not to send notification to that device anymore, but my question still remains: **Why is Apple not invalidating the token in case where I have deleted my app by erasing and resetting my iPhone?**

Maybe this is expected behaviour and my question doesn't make sense, but if it is expected behaviour, can you please point me to some documentation which is explaining this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely for the same reason that if you make a backup of your phone, and restore from backup, existing push keys still work. Invalidating the key on a device that is getting wiped would take out the potential that same key could be used from a backup.

Comment: Good point, but was kinda thinking that Apple is able to flag tokens of actually backed up apps and not invalidate them only.

Comment: If the backup is made on a computer without an internet connection, apple would have no way of knowing the backup exists. Restore a phone from that backup and the push tokens are still valid.